# a bit of culture clash -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

> Each subspecialty within information technology also has its own jargon that isn't shared by computer people outside that subspecialty. In the same way that **a bit of culture clash** is occurring as the language of computers enters the language of everyday life, so **a bit of culture clash** is occurring as the language of software internationalization enters the language of general computing.

I don't understand that phrase. Does **a bit** mean what it usually means, like a small part of something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A bit of culture clash* refers to the phenomenon caused by the medley of computer/programming language with the everyday language. I bet it's referred as *a bit of* because it's not such a big impact, let alone two actual cultures colliding together.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, "a bit of" means "some".  This is a figurative usage.

A literal usage of "a bit of" means "a small amount of", or "one-eighth of a one-dollar silver coin", or "a small amount that can be nibbled off of <something>."

Comment: Then, why didn't they say **a bit of a culture clash**? As far as I know, the word **clash** is countable in English, no?

Answer (score 0):

You could leave it out:
"A culture clash is occurring..."

The writer is stating a hard fact - the statement is obvious and agreed on.

However "A bit of a culture clash is occurring..."

This softens the statement, maybe it's just the writers opinion. It's not obvious, understated. Or just a way to reword and give the sentence some depth and color.